# search an aar file name in libs with java or kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I try to search my libs content in Android project for a specific AAR file name with java or Kotlin code. I searched a lot but can't find an answer.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: at the top of androud, click on Android and pick Project. you can see the external libs. you can also click on cmd click on the method name (for mac). and I think its shift click the method name on windows.

Comment: Thanks, I need to do a search in libs folder, looking for a file name in java or kotlin. it is not about searching with IDE

Comment: are you looking for a specific file (java or kotlin) within an aar?

Comment: I want to have a method to look inside libs and find if specific AAR file is inside libs or not or to return a list of the file names in libs.

Comment: within your own project? whats the purpose of this?

Comment: assume each user (BtoB SDK) needs different combination of AAR files to use.

Comment: for your app? you need to include dependencies into the application, regardless with the user is using them. this is beyond confused and your business case is confusing as well.

Comment: thanks for your time. I know I need to customize the Gradle for dependencies. My question is if it is possible--which there is no reason it is not--to search the content of libs folder.

Comment: to me, it sounds like you want to reverse engineer something. if you want to get into the libs folder from the app, no. if u want to get into the libs from outside the app... well, that wont be discussed here

Comment: Stackflow advised me not to extend the comments. First, as I said, I am working on an SDK, each user--sample app--till now, assumed that have all the AARs, but for more flexibility,  I want to change the SDK--not the app--to work with the different combination of AARs. Back to the question, if it is possible to each time call a method to check the content of libs and choose what path should take. Thanks for your time, but respect to the Stackflow, I can't send more comments.

Comment: its not up to you how the user interacts with the app..... its up to the app developer.  i think theres a lot of unknown here... either way, the answer is no. you dont have access to the libs folder... plus, AARs arent placed in a folder, they are added as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The way we solved it, to make a list--or enum--of all libraries and then try, catch to check a method in each library. if you get the result, you can add this library to an empty array list. do it for all libraries and the array list is the list of libraries that are available. 
don't forget to catch the right exception. I caught it with: NoClassDefFoundError. it is different due to your purpose.